# Avoding other team members commits in my merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I've recently moved from TFS to Git and like it pretty much.

My team at work use git-flow. For each feature, we create a feature branch. However, one thing that seems to happen occasionally is that, when pushing the feature branch and creating a pull request into `master`, there will be a merge conflict. In order to solve that merge conflict, I sync the `master` branch with remote and merge `master` with my feature branch and solve that merge conflict.

But now in my outgoing commits, not only will I have the "merge conflict fix" but I will also have all other commits in `master` that was made meanwhile, in that pull request.

Because if I merge my local branch with my local `master` and push from the `master`, I will bypass the pull request (even if this is technically possible here) but doesn't seem right. Am I wrong?

This problem isn't only during merge conflicts - I guess it's simply about keeping the feature branch in sync with the `master`. How do other people solve this? I've heard about rebasing but it seems like that is rarely being used in my team.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  If you merge the head of the remote master branch into your feature branch then yes, all the commits to master since you forked from it will become part of your branch history as well. But when you merge that back into the master they should not suddenly become *your* commits, nor should they be re-applied.

Comment: I think that's a normal display because your ̈PR display all the commits that will be included since the creation of the feature branch (and your sync merge will bring them). It's also probably a (bad?) design choice made by AzureDevops team because they could have excluded commits already included in the merged target branch. I think it could be solved by using a `rebase`. It's also a good practice to rebase feature branches to sync it to get a more easy to follow git history. So if you do it, will have an improvement. And it is still time to improve your team workflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Phlippe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730756/avoding-other-team-members-commits-in-my-merge#comment103753355_58730756) is correct: this is normal, because what you are seeing (in Visual Studio I assume?) is any commits on your feature branch that haven't yet been pushed to the remote.

Your commit history might look something like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E [master, origin/master]
 \           \
  X--Y--Z-----M [feature/mine]
         \
         [origin/feature/mine]
```

Where your work on the feature branch is commits X through Z, and commits B through E on master were someone else's work.

When you mention "outgoing commits", that is probably comparing your local branch `feature/mine` to the remote `origin/feature/mine`.  The latter "contains" commit A and everything before it, as well as your changes X, Y, & Z.  Your local branch, currently at commit M, also contains B through E, because you have merged those changes into your feature branch, so that is why you see those commits listed there.

This is not a problem, because Git still keeps track of who created commits B through E, you haven't magically claimed ownership of them or anything.  Also, since those commits are already contained in `origin/master`, they are already on the server, so you won't have to push them again.

---

I would likewise encourage you to consider rebasing instead of merging.  If you were on `feature/mine` at commit Z, you could do:

```
git rebase master
```

After resolving any conflicts and finishing the rebase, your history might look like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E [master, origin/master]
 \           \
  \           X'--Y'--Z' [feature/mine]
   \
    X--Y--Z [origin/feature/mine]
```

Then do:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

to update the remote feature branch.

This has the benefit of maintaining a cleaner history without the extra merge commits, but it's not required.  Assuming you make the same resolutions to any conflicts, then the code at commit M will look the same as that from commit Z'.

Notice that in this case your feature branch still contains commits B through E, they are just directly inherited from `master` rather than coming in through a merge commit.  This is okay and desired: the only way to resolve a merge conflict is to get the changes into your branch, where the conflict can be dealt with.